# Stumped: Cannot use class definition

Tags: iphone

I have a Owners class defined that is used just fine in existing classes.

I tried to add another class, and no matter what I do (deleted, recreated new class, copied other class files over and renamed, cleaned all targets, howled at the moon), I cannot use this particular class in any new files I create.

The class is simple with a singleton definition of an array.

Here it is in use in another class (just fine):

```
#import "OwnersSchema.h"
#import "Owners.h"
#import "Constants.h"

@implementation OwnersViewController
@synthesize mid,imageStore;

- (OwnersSchema *)OwnersForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
return [[Owners sharedOwners].ownersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

So I make an exact copy of the above header and make files, just rename interface, etc. and add the same exact code, and it claims Owners is undeclared: First use in function.

I can add other class definitions to the new file and it sees them just fine.

Here is the Owners class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "URLConnection.h"
@class OwnersSchema;

@interface Owners : NSObject <URLCacheConnectionDelegate> {
NSMutableArray *ownersArray;
NSString *lastUpdated;
NSString *url;
NSString *dbpath;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *dbpath;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *ownersArray;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *lastUpdated;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString  *url;
-(void)saveOwnersArray;
+ (Owners *)sharedOwners;
@end
```

I don't get it.  I just want to create another viewcontroller. Is there some limitation on the number of files or class inclusions (actually, I use this Owners class in only a few places).  And why does it work everywhere else except for the new class I'm trying to create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I cleaned all targets again, then ran clean caches, then restarted, and the class is usable again.

Answer (score 1):

Try a clean and rebuild?